# Algebra word problem (down below)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem: A website describes how to make a parabolic dish with a wok and a microphone attached to the focal point.  You have a wok 22 inches wide (shown as vertical on the paper) and 8 inches deep (shown as horizontal).  Write an equation that represents the cross section of the wok.  Find the location of the microphone as well.

Background info (for anyone asking if I attempted problem): For this one, it was asking to find the focus. I thought the focus was (8,0), so in x = 1/4p * y^2, I subbed in 8 as p and got x = 1/32 y^2.  However, one of the points supposed to be on the graph was (8,13), which wasn't on the equation I got.  So, I'm sure what I did was wrong.

[image]

Comment: Where is the origin?  If it is the vertex of the parabola with the $x$ axis the axis of the parabola, then the point should be $(8,11)$.  Why should the focus be at the exit plane?  You should choose $p$ so that $(8,11)$ is on the graph.  That will tell you where the focus is.

Comment: Ross, the origin is shown to be at (0,0).  And with all of the given information, how would I find the focus?

Comment: I don't see a link to the picture or I would have pasted it in.  First you find the equation in the form $x=Ay^2$ from the point you have.  Then you have been told that $A=\frac p4$

Answer (score 0):

First you find the equation in the form $x=Ay^2$ from the point you have.  Then you have been told that $A=\frac p4$